# Understanding how functions/variables work inside of class

Tags: python, class

I'm working on a Python project that downloads YouTube videos when a user enters name of the video. I never worked with a class and this is my first time and I actually learned from a Python book about class, function and all, but when I try to use it in a real project, I am so confused. Here is my code:

```
import pytube
import urllib.request
import urllib.parse
import re

class YouTubeDownloader:
    def __init__(self):
        self.user_music = self.userInput()

    # Ask user what video they want to download
    def userInput(self):
        print("Please type such as: Chopin Nocturne No 9 op 5")
        subject = input("What video do you want to download in YouTube?")
        return subject

    # Search the youtube video with what user type
    def searchYoutube(self, subject):
        query_string = urllib.parse.urlencode({"search_query": subject})
        html_content = urllib.request.urlopen("http://www.youtube.com/results?" + query_string)
        search_results = re.findall(r'href=\"\/watch\?v=(.{11})', html_content.read().decode())
        finalURL = "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=" + search_results[0]
        return finalURL

    # Download the first video
    def downloadVideo(self, finalURL):
        youtube = pytube.YouTube(finalURL)
        video = youtube.streams.first()
        video.download('C:/Users/Muffin/Downloads')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    user = YouTubeDownloader()
```

So here:

1. Do I need `self.user_music`, and if so why do I need it? I'm not passing anything to `__init__` other then *self*, is it necessary?
2. I want to use the `subject` variable from the function `def userInput`, in `def searchYoutube`, does variable automatically passes to different functions within the class?

Comment: The function scope inside a class is the same as outside a class – functions cannot access the local variables of another, separate function. Whether you use a class or not, you have to orchestrate the functions/methods in the same way. Note that this isn't a good use-case for a class – there is no state shared between the methods.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi but I have function 'userInput' that returns subject, and I want to use the subject variable for the next function 'searchYoutube'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Your code never seems to be using `self.user_music`, so, based on the code snippet you provided, you don't need to define it. If you are not passing anything to `__init__`, and don't need to do any custom initialization during object instantiation, you don't need to define a constructor (`__init__`) because Python will provide a default constructor for you.
2. Names defined inside a function belong to the function's local scope and are not visible outside of that scope. If you want to use the value of `subject`, you need to pass it as an argument to all other functions or methods that might want to use it. You can turn it into an instance attribute: `self.subject = 'whatever'`, and use it when needed; in such case, you don't need to pass it around.

Please note that the answers are based on the current code snippet. We don't see how you use `searchYoutube` or `downloadVideo`, so the final answer might be different.

EDIT: Updating the code as per the request in comments to show how to create an instance variable `subject`.

```
import pytube
import urllib.request
import urllib.parse
import re

class YouTubeDownloader:
    def __init__(self):
        self.subject = self.userInput()

    # Ask user what video they want to download
    def userInput(self):
        print("Please type such as: Chopin Nocturne No 9 op 5")
        subject = input("What video do you want to download in YouTube?")
        return subject

    # Search the youtube video with what user type
    def searchYoutube(self):
        query_string = urllib.parse.urlencode({"search_query": self.subject})
        html_content = urllib.request.urlopen("http://www.youtube.com/results?" + query_string)
        search_results = re.findall(r'href=\"\/watch\?v=(.{11})', html_content.read().decode())
        finalURL = "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=" + search_results[0]
        return finalURL

    # Download the first video
    def downloadVideo(self, finalURL):
        youtube = pytube.YouTube(finalURL)
        video = youtube.streams.first()
        video.download('C:/Users/Muffin/Downloads')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    youtube_downloader = YouTubeDownloader()

    # Example of searching YouTube
    final_url = youtube_downloader.searchYoutube()
```

Comment: So then I do need __init__ to add self.subject = 'whatever', correct??

Comment: @sarahkim Stricly speaking - no. Python allows you to define instance attributes after the object initialization (outside of the constructor), though that is not recommended. If you intend to use `self.subject`, it would be best to define it inside the `__init__` and change its value in other methods.

Comment: Is this a bad way of using class? For this project, do you think it's better not to use the class?

Comment: @sarahkim It's fine, though you might want to rename `self.user_music` to `self.subject`, remove the parameter `subject` from method `searchYoutube` and access `self.subject` instead of just `subject`.

Comment: Would you mind showing me how to fix my code? I created self.subject = subject and try to access self.subject instead but I get a lot of additional errors...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211023/discussion-between-sarah-kim-and-hgazibara).